# Finite Cyclic Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cryptography, cyclic-groups

Let G be a finite cyclic group with |G|=n. Let $g\in G$. Prove if $g^x \neq 1 \ \forall x \in [1,\frac n3]$, then either the ord(g)=n, or n is even and the ord(g)=$\frac n2$.

I am at a loss on how to even start this. Should I start by plugging in the bounds?

Comment: Well, the order of $g$ has to be a divisor of $n$ so...  Note:  I don't see where you need $G$ to be cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The order of $g$ divides $n$. If $d$ divides $n$ and $d > \frac n3$, then $\frac nd < 3$.